# Function encapsulated in class to load required files just once

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have got an algorithm that has got one function calculate(x, y) which calls many smaller functions which require to use two big files that I want to load only once.

One way to load it once is to load them and pass them to calculate(x, y, f1, f2) and they will be passed to next and next functions that are called inside.

```
def calculate(x, y, f1, f2):
    a = function1(x, y, f1) 
    b = function2(x, y, f2)

def function1(x, y, f1):
    #process further with f1 that is passed by arg further and further...
```

Other way is to make a class

```
class Algo
    def __init__():
         self.f1 = load_f1...
         self.f2 = load_f2...

    def calculate(self, x, y):
        a = function1(x, y) 
        b = function2(x, y)

    def function1(self, x, y):
        #process further with self.f1...
```

and load files in init and call it this way.
Is it proper way to encapsulate function in a class?
Is there any pattern that solves that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common technique for solving this problem is encapsulating the large files in an object and passing those objects to the constructor of your algorithm class. For example:

```
class Algo
    def __init__(self, file1, file2):
         self.f1 = file1
         self.f2 = file2

    def calculate(self, x, y):
        a = function1(x, y) 
        b = function2(x, y)

    def function1(self, x, y):
        #process further with self.f1...
```

Opening the files is the responsibility of the object that creates the `Algo` object. For example:

```
large_file_1 = open("some_file.txt")
large_file_2 = open("some_other_file.txt")
algo = Algo(large_file_1, large_file_2)
```

It may seem like a minor difference between passing the files into the constructor as arguments or simply opening the files within the constructor (as in your second example), but there are some important distinctions:

1. The responsibility of opening the files is moved outside of the `Algo` class
2. Fake files can be injected into the `Algo` class for testing

In the first case, the `Algo` class should only be concerned with the execution of your desired algorithm. Although opening a file may not seem like a difference of a responsibility, what if the logic for opening the file were to change? For example, suppose that the files were later compressed as `.zip` files to save space: The `Algo` class *should not* have to change. Instead, the creator of the `Algo` object would be responsible for altering how the files are opened. From the perspective of the `Algo` class, as long as a file handle is provided, it does not care if the file was stored as text, binary, compressed text, etc. By passing the files as arguments to the `Algo` constructor, we ensure that the `Algo` class is decoupled from the specific representation of the file.

In the second case, we are able to test the `Algo` class in isolation. Instead of using real data, we could inject fake files and test that the algorithm works with those fake files. If we had included the logic for opening the files within the body of the constructor, the `Algo` class would be forced to use the production (non-test) files and would be unable to test against faked/stubbed data.

Answer (score 0):

I think, concerning the SRP principle, it is definitevily possible to use an own class just for loading your two big files.
I think it seems way more logic to use an own class rather then calling different methods, because as an user of your interface (or however youre code will be used) i don't want to call several different methods, i just want to do

```
FileLoader fileLoader = new FileLoeader();
List<File> loadedFiles = fileLoeader.init(filePaths);

public class FileLoader() {
private List<File> readFiles;
public void init(List<String> filePaths) { filePaths.foreach(s -> loadFile(s) }

public int calculate(Algorithm alg) { ... }

}
```

If you need this files only for your mentioned calculations, you could simply do the init and then call the calculation method in this class and inject your desired algorithm.
If you want to retreive the files for further use, you could store them in an accessible list like i showed in the code example. My example is java but can be transformed to any other language.